# devise confirmation emails sent via gmail end up in spam box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using devise for authentication in my Rails app. It seemed to be working but we just went live with our site and confirmation emails are now tagged as spam. How can I solve this?

My environment vars:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :enable_starttls_auto => true,
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => "gmail.com",
      :authentication => :login,
      :user_name => "account@gmail.com",
      :password => "password"
  }
```

Comment: What do the subject and body of the email look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use your own domain instead of `gmail.com`. I don't think you'll have any control over this as **gmail** is a free mail domain so alot of spam originates from there...so mail clients (and ISP) spam filters will sort it as such because it appears to be unsolicited.

Or, maybe it's something in the **content** of your message that's triggering the junk/spam filters?!?

Answer (score 0):

there were two problems.

- the first was that i sent mail to the same address too many times while testing.
- the second problem was that the domain of the server differed from the address (as Meltemi suggested).

i resolved this by setting up a google apps account until i have mail server.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue has been addressed on the mailgun blog:

http://blog.mailgun.com/tips-tricks-avoiding-gmail-spam-filtering-when-using-ruby-on-rails-action-mailer/

> The issue is that if you do not specify the message-ID, Action Mailer
>   populates this header with a default value which may not be a valid
>   message-ID. In addition, if you are connecting to an SMTP relay, that
>   message-ID probably does not reflect the domain that is actually
>   sending the email.  It may say something like
>   "<[uid]@localhost.localdomain>".
>
> Gmail is very strict about making sure that the message-ID in the MIME
>   headers follows RFC 2822 and that the domain in the message-ID is the
>   same as the sending domain.

I'm looking into using Gmail or Mailgun. Its a small app so not something I want to be dropping money on per month while I am playing.